# Hide and show multiple divs with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide and show two divs with one click.

```
<a href="javascript:showhide('bbb','ccc4')">
    you click here to see two div contents </a>sddsds<br />
</a>
```

I have been able to only hide and show one div. When I try to hide and show two divs, using ID, I can't. I've tried some other suggestions, but they do not work.

```
<a href="javascript:showhide('bbb','ccc4')">
    you click here to see two div contents </a>sddsds<br />
</a>

<div target='ccc4' name='ccc4'  id='ccc4' frameborder='0'onload='setIframeHeight(this.id)'   style='display:none;'  ' > ddfddddd

    <iframe class='shark'  src='imagehugeblow.php?midd=<?=$row5['mid'] ?>ccc' target='ccc' name='ccc'  id='ccc' frameborder='0'onload='setIframeHeight(this.id)'     style='display:none;'              ></iframe>

</div> <div target='bbb' name='bbb'  id='bbb' frameborder='0'onload='setIframeHeight(this.id)'   style='display:none;'  ' > sdds

    <iframe class='shark'  src='imagehugeblow.php?midd=<?=$row5['mid'] ?>ccc' target='bbb' name='bbb'  id='bbb' frameborder='0'onload='setIframeHeight(this.id)'     style='display:none;'              ></iframe>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
</script>
```

I've tried using the Javascript below, but it doesn't work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility() {
        for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < e; i++) {
            var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style,d = e.display;
            e.display = (d == "block") ? "none" : "block";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Is there a way to hide more than one div with one click, or must I use class instead of using ID?

Comment: Use a comma if you want to pass more than one parm. However using a javascript href is also not recommended - instead use the click event and return false - as in `<a href="turnonjs.html" onclick="return toggle_visibility('bbb','ccc4')">`

Comment: sorry I did add commas and was playing around with it and left a dot accidently instead of a comma but it still didn't work.

Comment: `d = e.display` is wrong, you must use `d = e.style.display`

Comment: okay thanks everyone d = e.style.display was corrected and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Here you are dealing only with one ID.

Rewirite your function to hide two IDs. Something like that:

```
function showhide(id1, id2) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id1);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    e = document.getElementById(id2);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

To reduce code replication use array to store ids:

```
function showhide(ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var e = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
        e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
showhide(['bbb', 'ccc4'])
```

Or you can use `arguments`:

```
function showhide() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```

In this case call should be:

```
showhide('bbb', 'ccc4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each div you want to toggle display as a seperate parameter:

```
<a href="javascript:showhide('bbb', 'ccc4')">
```

Then change your JS to include a loop over the arguments array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showhide() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
      var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
      e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My version

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("ccc4").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("bbb").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("toggle").onclick=function() {
    var divs = this.getAttribute("data-divs").split(",");
   
    for(var i = 0,len = divs.length;i < len;i++){
      var e = document.getElementById(divs[i]).style;
      console.log(e.display)
      e.display = (e.display == "") ? "none" : "";
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="turnonjs.html" id="toggle" data-divs="ccc4,bbb">
    you click here to see two div contents </a>


<div target='ccc4' name='ccc4'  id='ccc4'>div 1</div> 
<div target='bbb' name='bbb'  id='bbb'> div 2</div>
```

Or give both divs the same class and use `document.querySelectorAll(".classname")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')e.style.display = 'none'; 
    else e.style.display = 'block'; }
</script>

<a onclick="toggle_visibility('div-to-hide');">

<div id="div-to-hide" class="div-to-hide">
---- content here ---
</div>
```